# Problem with publishing tools is laravel nova

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs3, laravel-nova

Laravel 10, nova 4.25.1. I have a problem with publishing tools. I create according to the documentation. I register in the provider, specify in fields, run npm run dev, prod, watch. Nothing helps and the tool does not appear on the page and the js code that is in Tool.vue is not executed.

Hello! Laravel 10, nova 4.25.1. I have a problem with publishing tools. I create according to the documentation. I register in the provider, specify in fields, run npm run dev, prod, watch. Nothing helps and the tool does not appear on the page and the js code that is in Tool.vue is not executed. Please help me solve the problem!